# AppleScript or Automator flow to import photos into iphoto and set album name as files folder name

Tags: applescript, automator, iphoto

I store photo files in folders on my computer before i add them into iphoto.

I want to add the contents of a selected to folder to iphoto and name the new album as the folder name

I have created an automator flow where I do the following

(Select folder initially to work)

1. Get selected finder items -- This is grabbing the folder
2. Set Value of Variable -- this is grabbing the full path name and setting a variable with the name
3. Get Folder contents -- this gets all the photos contained.
4. Import Files into iphoto -- This adds the photos into iphoto and creates a new album using the variable name.

The issue i have is the variable name sets the full path of the files, 
/Users/Johnny/Photos/Dayout

Is the a script that can take just the name of the initial folder "Dayout"

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Cheers

John

Comment: care to share the script with me, please ? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activate application "SystemUIServer" -- http://www.openradar.me/9406282
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat with f in (get selection as alias list)
        set n to name of f
        tell application "iPhoto"
            if not (exists album n) then new album name n
            import from f to album n
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

There is a bug in 10.7 and 10.8 where Finder ignores new windows when getting the selection property. If you open a new Finder window, select some items, and run `tell app "Finder" to selection` in AppleScript Editor, the result is items selected in some window behind the frontmost window (or an empty list). One workaround is to move focus to another application and back.